# Best way to communicate with a device without freezing GUI

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, communication

I'm new to c# and now need to build a GUI which controls a test system with multiple devices. I've created a classlibrary (dll) for each device. Now I want to send some commands to them using methods.

But parts of the communication can take some time, for example getting raw data from an oscilloscope or checking its connection state using a timer. This results in a GUI freezes.

So now I'm wondering what would be the best way to outsource this communication to a different thread?. All communications are independent and i could do most of them in parallel. So what I'm basically looking for is a way to for example create a whole class in a different worker, call a method and let it answer in form of an event.

Edit:
The communication is done using "ActiveDSO", which is a special way used by Lecroy Oscilloscopes (The actual thing is done using ethernet but I only call functions of their 3rd party lib).
Actually changing to .Net 4.5 + using asyc/await solved my problem, thanks.

Comment: So, you have figured out that you need multiple threads.  Exactly what are you asking here?  How to do thread programming in C# ?

Comment: You know you need a different thread, so just look up C#'s ways to do threading. Like the for example the Task Parallel Library: [TPL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You need to describe this “communication”; is it over USB? The internet? If it is blocked on I/O, spinning up another thread will just block your new thread. In that case investigate [async/await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443(v=vs.140).aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Async and Await can help you with your problem.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443(v=vs.110)#BKMK_WhentoUseAsynchrony

Here's an example https://www.dotnetperls.com/async

Answer (score 0):

Use `async` and `await` keywords: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async